# Jquery text limit without removing active tags

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to limit the length of some dynamic titles on a project by using the following Jquery..

**EDIT improvement via @Utkanos**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){
  $(".newsTitle").each(function(i){
    var len=$(this).text().length;
    if(len>40) // If more than 35 characters then..
    {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,40)+'...'); // then add ...
      }
    });       
  });
});
```

I need to be able to limit the title length however not damage the link tags wrapped around the title. Is this possible? This is the HTML I am having to work with.

```
<h2 class="newsTitle">
    <a href="/blog/new-story">Lorem Ipsum ameh dolor sit loremip ipsum</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: Is there always a link child of `h2.newsTitle`?

Comment: Beware the (seemingly) global var, `len`

Comment: You have a global var - `len`. This should be a local var - just prefix it with `var `. Global variables should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$(".newsTitle")
```

to:

```
$(".newsTitle a")
```

That way you are correctly manipulating the node that contains the text, not it’s parent that also contains the anchor element.

Comment: Oh my lord, how did i miss such a simple thing. Thank you, in 12 minutes i will assign you the right answer. Thanks again good sir.. doh!